# Convert sub-hourly data to hourly and round up time in R

Tags: r, date

I have a very big dataframe in R, containing weather data with the following format.

```
                 valid temp
    1 17/08/2014 00:20   14
    2 17/08/2014 00:50   14
    3 17/08/2014 01:20   13.5
    4 17/08/2014 01:50   13
    5 17/08/2014 02:20   12
    6 17/08/2014 02:50   10
```

I would like to convert these sub-hourly data to hourly, like the following.

```
                    valid tmpc
    1 2014-08-17 00:00:00   14
    2 2014-08-17 01:00:00   13.75
    3 2014-08-17 02:00:00   12.5
```

The class of df$valid is 'factor'. I have tried first converting them to Date through POSIXct, but it gives only NA values. I have also tried changing the system locale and still I get NAs.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: The `lubridate` solution using `ceiling_date` or `round_date`. It's not clear according to your data frame and results if what you want is to round or ceiling. For instance, in the first row you are rounding and in the third  using ceiling. Anyways here the example:

```
library(lubridate)
df <- data.frame(i = 1, valid= "17/08/2014 01:28", temp = 14)
df$valid <- dmy_hm(df$valid)
df$valid_round <- ceiling_date(df$valid , unit="hours")
```

Results:

```
  i               valid temp         valid_round
1 1 2014-08-17 01:28:00   14 2014-08-17 02:00:00
```

Option 2: using the `base` functions. Use:
    df$valid <- as.POSIXct(strptime(df$valid, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", tz ="UTC")) 
and then round it.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this in `base R` by converting to `POSIXlt`, set the `minute` to 0, convert it back to `POSIXct` and `aggregate` to get the `mean` of 'temp'

```
df1$valid <- strptime(df1$valid, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
df1$valid$min <- 0
df1$valid <- as.POSIXct(df1$valid)
aggregate(temp~valid, df1, FUN = mean)
```

Comment: unfortunately, I still get <NA> in the date format.

Comment: @peny Then, please check the format.  This is based on your example and it works for me